# Problema con variable en JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy teniendo problemas con una variable que tengo definida en una función de JQUERY, y dentro de un if le doy el valor correspondiente. Siempre me devuelve "undefined" y no se porqué ya que está definida... Al aparecer este error, no puedo seguir con al ejecución de mi script, ya que genera un error al generar el PDF. Adjunto la llamada a la función, la Función y el fragmento de HTML, agradezco toda ayuda.

***Llamada a la función***

```
//GENERAR OFERTA LIBRE O DE UN ARTICULO
$("#imprimirOferta").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if($("#imagenProductoBD").attr("src") == '' && $("#resultadoImagen").attr("src") == ''){
        $("#imagenProductoFija").addClass("error");

        $("#spanError").show();
        $("#spanError").append("Debe introducir una imagen");
    }else{
        imprimirOfertaLibre($("#nombreArticulo").val());
    }
});
```

***LA FUNCIÓN***

```
    function imprimirOfertaLibre(nombreArticulo){
    

    // comprobamos la imagen que estamos seleccionando
    // si la introducimos a mano o viene de la BD
    let imagenProducto = "";

    if($("#imagenProductoBD").attr("src") == ""){
        imagenProducto = $("#resultadoImagen").attr("src");
    }else{
        imagenProducto = $("#imagenProductoBD").attr("src");
    }

    console.log(imagenProducto);
    

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://10.48.0.19/control/controladores/generarOfertaPDF.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "logo": $("#logoEmpresaResultado").attr("src"),
            "nombreCliente": $("#nombreCliente").val(),
            "apellidosCliente": $("#apellidosCliente").val(),
            "telefonoCliente": $("#telefonoCliente").val(),
            "dniCliente": $("#dniCliente").val(),
            "fechaOferta": $("#fechaOferta").val(),
            "precioOferta": $("#precioOferta").val(),
            "nombreArticulo": nombreArticulo,
            "imagenProducto": imagenProducto,
            "detallesArticulo": $("#detallesArticulo").val()
        },
        success: function(response){
            window.open("http://10.48.0.19/control/controladores/ofertaLibre.pdf", "pdf");
            console.log(response);
        },

        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                console.log('Not connect: Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                console.log('Requested page not found [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                console.log('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {
                console.log('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
                console.log('Time out error.');
            } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {
                console.log('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                console.log('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

La variable que intento mostrar y enviar al PHP es la del console.log, y siempre es undefined.

***HTML***

```
$articulo = DB::queryExecute("SELECT * FROM comparador WHERE codigo='$idArticulo'");

                        // nombre del articulo
                        echo "<label for='tituloProducto'>Titulo Articulo:</label>";
                        echo "<input type='text' id='nombreArticulo' value='".$articulo[0]['titulo']."'/>";
                    
                            
                            $portada = $articulo[0]['portada'];
                            echo "<img src='$portada' alt='' name='imagenProductoBD' class='imagenProductoBD' id='imagenProductoBD'";

                            echo "<p><b>Si no hay imagen Introduzca dirección imagen:</b></p>";
                            echo "<input type='text' id='imagenProductoFija'>";
                            echo "<img src='' name='imagenProducto' class='imagenProducto' id='resultadoImagen'/>";
                            echo "<span class='errorSpan' id='spanError'></span>";
```

***FUNCIÓN MODIFICADA***

```
function imprimirOfertaLibre(nombreArticulo){


// comprobamos la imagen que estamos seleccionando
// si la introducimos a mano o viene de la BD
let imagenProducto = "";

if($("#resultadoImagen").attr("src") || $("#imagenProductoBD").attr("src")){
    if($("#imagenProductoBD").attr("src") != ""){
        imagenProducto = $("#imagenProductoBD").attr("src");
    }else{
        imagenProducto = $("#resultadoImagen").attr("src");
    }
}else{
    Alert('Error ninguna imagen cargada!!!');
    return;
}


$.ajax({
    url: "http://10.48.0.19/control/controladores/generarOfertaPDF.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "logo": $("#logoEmpresaResultado").attr("src"),
        "nombreCliente": $("#nombreCliente").val(),
        "apellidosCliente": $("#apellidosCliente").val(),
        "telefonoCliente": $("#telefonoCliente").val(),
        "dniCliente": $("#dniCliente").val(),
        "fechaOferta": $("#fechaOferta").val(),
        "precioOferta": $("#precioOferta").val(),
        "nombreArticulo": nombreArticulo,
        "imagenProducto": imagenProducto,
        "detallesArticulo": $("#detallesArticulo").val()
    },
    success: function(response){
        window.open("http://10.48.0.19/control/controladores/ofertaLibre.pdf", "pdf");
        console.log(response);
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            console.log('Not connect: Verify Network.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            console.log('Requested page not found [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            console.log('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {
            console.log('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
            console.log('Time out error.');
        } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {
            console.log('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            console.log('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

}

***PHP***

```
if($_POST["imagenProducto"]){
    $imagen_url = $_POST["imagenProducto"];

    $imagen = "";

    if(exif_imagetype($imagen_url) != IMAGETYPE_PNG){
        $imagen = "imagen.jpg";
    }else{
        $imagen = "imagen.png";
    }

    $metodocurl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($metodocurl, CURLOPT_URL, $imagen_url);
    curl_setopt($metodocurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($metodocurl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    $curlDatos = curl_exec ($metodocurl);

    curl_close ($metodocurl);


    $miarchivo = fopen($imagen, "w+");

    fputs($miarchivo, $curlDatos);

    fclose($miarchivo);
}
```

***salida en consola***

```
    imagen.jpg<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Image file name is empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php:271

Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php(868): FPDF-&gt;Error('Image file name...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\generarOfertaPDF.php(10): FPDF-&gt;Image('', 10, 15, 90)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php(334): PDF-&gt;Header()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\generarOfertaPDF.php(185): FPDF-&gt;AddPage()
#4 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\control\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php</b> on line <b>271</b><br />
```

Como se puede ver, el imagen.jpg se supone que es el archivo resultante... Pero no lo genera bien, al intentar abrirla, dice que está vacía la imagen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si tu caso es
`<img id="imagenProductoBD" />`

en ausencia de del atributo src tu variable sería siempre undefided dado que esto es lo que obtienes al evaluar:

[image: console chrome]

tu código debiera ser algo como esto:

```
if($("#resultadoImagen").attr("src") || $("#imagenProductoBD").attr("src")){
    if($("#imagenProductoBD").attr("src") != ""){
        imagenProducto = $("#imagenProductoBD").attr("src");
    }else{
        imagenProducto = $("#resultadoImagen").attr("src");
    }
}else{
    alert('Error ninguna imagen cargada!!!');
    return;
}
```

Comment: Así que tendría que evaluar de otra manera o como podría hacerlo¿?? yo lo que quiero preguntar es si la imagen de la BD es vacia o nula que coga el valor de una imagen que genero con js por medio de un input text

Comment: ahí agregué una forma más adecuada de preguntar

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. He editado mi pregunta para ver si me puedes ayudar, ya que no consigo generar un PDF con FPDF pasandole la imagen que obtengo de una URL, ya sea de la BD o introduciéndola a mano.